# word limit in Tiny MCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have 4 Tiny MCE editor in my application on same page. I want to put max word limit to 100 (editor1 + editor 2 + editor 3 + editor 4 word count must be less than 100 words).  whenever I should click on submit button the webpage should chaeck this validation ( or whenever the count increases more than 100 then the same page before clicking on submit button should alert the user)

I have gone through many online solution but not able to know how I can implement this functionality.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >


     tinyMCE.init({
         selector: 'textArea',  // change this value according to your HTML
         menu: {
             edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
             insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr' },
             format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic superscript subscript' },
             tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' }
         },
         resize: 'both',
         plugins: "wordcount",
         encoding: "xml"            

     });
 var myVar = parseInt($('#content-word-count').text()); 
 if (myVar > 100){ "Your information exceeded than the max limit 100" };

</script>

<textarea id="editor1" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea> <br />
<textarea id="editor2" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea> <br />
<textarea id="editor3" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea> <br />
<textarea id="editor4" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea> <br />

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask any instance of TinyMCE for its current word count like this:

```
var editor1 = tinymce.get('editor1');
editor1.plugins.wordcount.getCount();
```

If you need to add the count from multiple editors you can expand this to get this information from each instance of TinyMCE.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  If so it will help others to mark the answer as correct.  If not - what remaining issues do you have?